# Mistakenly encrypted partition while installing Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, live-usb, encryption, lvm

My friend has tried to install Ubuntu on her USB (with live-usb) and used LMV encryption for the USB. Right now, it is not possible to load Windows normally. It seems she mistakenly encrypt her laptop's HDD.

When we tried to use Ubuntu on USB it shows her laptop's HDD as "Encrypted". she remembers that it shows the following error while she wanted to install Ubuntu on her USB:

> **Volume group name already in use**
>
> The volume group name used to automatically partition using LVM is already in use. Lowering the priority for configuration questions will allow you to specify an alternative name.

I don't know how to solve this problem and recover the windows **without** loosing the data.

Comment: LVM is normally a full drive erase. If she selected the wrong drive then Windows may be gone. Post this with all drives plugged in. `sudo parted -l` Did she have good backups of Windows & her data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any simple solution because all data were deleted and the whole HDD was encrypted but I used TestDisk to recover all data. That helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get it back but you'd have to move the whole file system (or all files) to another drive or partition (with enough free space) or an external HDD. Then, remove the encrypted container, and recreate the file system in its entirety without encryption. Finally, make sure that the new file system is properly recognized and that nothing has gone wrong. 
The processes used are 
1) Very complex 
2) very time consuming 
3) error prone.

There is no "quick fix" unfortunately but there is a lot of information available if you look.

Good luck!