# 'Volume group name already in use' - message during ubuntu 18.04 installation

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, encryption, lvm

While trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 (from usb) to an ssd disk, and choosing 'Erase disk and install Ubuntu', with encryption and LVM, I get the following message:

> **Volume group name already in use**
>
> The volume group name used to automatically partition using LVM is already in use. Lowering the priority for configuration questions will allow you to specify an alternative name.

After clicking 'ok', I get to what looks like an empty partition table (manager), and I can only pick sda from a drop down menu, and there's no partitions showing at all; basically I can't seem to do much from there.

I did not find much on this issue, only these threads: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616093/mistakenly-encrypted-partition-while-installing-ubuntu), [2](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lubuntu-users/2015-October/010040.html), [3](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/5rzude/linux_mint_booting_into_incorrect_hard_drive/) ; which are either not answered or do not actually resolve what the message is about and how it can be fixed.

**Question(s):** Can and would anyone explain what this message means, and how I may resolve the issue, so that I can just install Ubuntu onto the drive (ATA KINGSTON SA400S3) with encryption? I have no other requirements, I just want a clean encrypted installation on that drive; there's nothing on it at the moment.

**System details:**

I am on an intel i7 PC with 4 drives in total (1 running windows, 1 running Ubuntu 18.04; I think the bootloader is on the windows drive); now I want a second Ubuntu drive. Here's the output of `sudo parted -l`:

```
 Model: ATA INTEL SSDSC2CW18 (scsi)
 Disk /dev/sda: 180GB
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
 Partition Table: msdos
 Disk Flags: 

 Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
  1      1049kB  180GB  180GB  primary  ntfs         boot


 Model: ATA KINGSTON SHFS37A (scsi)
 Disk /dev/sdb: 240GB
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
 Partition Table: msdos
 Disk Flags: 

 Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
  1      1049kB  240GB  240GB  primary               lvm


 Model: ATA ST1000VX000-9YW1 (scsi)
 Disk /dev/sdc: 1000GB
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
 Partition Table: msdos
 Disk Flags: 

 Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
  1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ntfs


 Model: ATA KINGSTON SA400S3 (scsi)
 Disk /dev/sdd: 240GB
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
 Partition Table: msdos
 Disk Flags: 

 Number  Start   End    Size   Type      File system  Flags
  1      1049kB  768MB  767MB  primary   ext4
  2      769MB   240GB  239GB  extended
  5      769MB   240GB  239GB  logical


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 239GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0,00B  239GB  239GB  ext4


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 1028MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0,00B  1028MB  1028MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the guided installer uses the hostname you set earlier in the install and appends '-vg' to it when setting up the logical volume groups. Change the hostname to not conflict during install and you can have two ubuntu guided setup lvm installs on different disks.

To install and overwrite the same disk fresh, you need to remove the volume group manually since the installer won't do it. Think too much could go wrong automating messing with peoples LVM setup...

Instead of choosing a different hostname for my use case, I just renamed the volume group on the first disk to something else when it gave me that warning. Here's how:

Suppose you chose 'machine' as your hostname during the first install, then when you get the 'Volume group name already in use' message during the second install, do this..

1. Use Alt-F2 to get to a command prompt
2. Enter command: vgdisplay

   - this shows that there is a volume group already with the name 'machine-vg'
3. Enter: vgrename -v machine-vg machine-vg-1

   - replace 'machine' with your hostname of course
4. Use Alt-F1 to get back to the installer, and complete the guided install.

Now I have two fresh installs on different disks, that should be identical except for the logical volume group names.

For fresh install over a previous guided install with lvm, I think you would use the command 'vgremove machine-vg' in step 3 above instead of vgrename.

So my basic understanding is: You need to remove lvm manually from the disk you are installing to, or rename volume groups on other disks where the name conflicts, before the partitioner in the installer can automatically create the partition tables for guided lvm installs.

By the way, I have also experienced a lubuntu 18.04 installer kicking back to the install page (install loop), with no warning messages whatsover. Thinking about this now, have a feeling it was the same problem: LVM was already setup on the disk I was using for lvm install. However, since the names didn't conflict, no error message at all, just a blank screen then back to the install button.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem (22.04 LTS).

At the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" page

There is a "Write changes to disk" popup

I accidentally pressed the "go back". Afterwards I would always get  that "Volume group name already in use" error, and couldn't continue.

I simply rebooted the computer and did the installation from scratch again. This time i made sure not to click that "go back" button. That worked.